# Adding Text On Export Seems To Ignore SPAN Styling

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

Upon exporting we are adding some additional text to the chart as the `title`. This works, however, the text formatting is not obeying to my mind what it should look like. The `title` code which is in a select box:

```
title: { text: '<span style="text-align:center; font-weight:bold;">Labor Force, Employment and Unemployment for Florida in Multiple Time Periods</span><br /><br /><span style="text-align:center; font-weight:bold;font-size:9pt">Labor Force Area Distribution Graph</span><br /><br /><span style="text-align:left; font-size:10px">The graph below shows the Counties in Florida with the highest monthly not seasonally adjusted unemployment rate in June, 2013.</span>' }
```

The text in question is `<span style="text-align:left; font-size:10px">The graph below shows the Counties in Florida with the highest monthly not seasonally adjusted unemployment rate in June, 2013.</span>`. This is not left aligned and it also has an extra large line break when it goes to a new line.

Here is a live [**example**](http://jsfiddle.net/wergeld/X3EE5/).

Comment: This is how I see your chart before exporting (just copy&pasted options from form to chart object): http://jsfiddle.net/X3EE5/3/

Comment: Correct. The issue is that I cannot set a per-line alignment. There are three components to our exported chart's title. the first 2 are centered and the last line (begins with "The graph below shows the Counties...") should be left-aligned. I can only set the chart's title using `title.align` and it ignores anything in the title's `span` tags. In your example fiddle you see that the all the text is centered.

Comment: All css tags are translated to svg elements. So, CSS is applied to tspan's. Highcharts won't calculate 'text-align` to pixel position. Instead you have title and subtitle, so could you place left-aligned texts to the subtitle, and centered texts to the title?

Comment: This would work but we already use subtitle for other the "Source:..." footer. So, we would need another title or text element. We had experimented with using the renderer to add in a text element but we have so many possible variations of lengths of the text that positioning became an issue.

Comment: Indeed, `renderer.text()` is solution on your case. Then how about using [`labels`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#labels) instead?

Comment: The `labels` looks like a direction I will look at.

Comment: @PawełFus, the `labels` approach is not working either. See http://jsfiddle.net/wergeld/X3EE5/4/ and use JPEG export link. I altered the 3 blocks of text to all use `align: center` and yet all are left aligned and the text overflows the container. If I get this block of text to fit (by adjusting `spacingLeft` and `spacingTop`) I am still left with having to adjust hundreds of other possible combination of text. The usefulness of `title` and `subtitle` is that it observes the chart's dimensions and does not overflow. Can we use the `credits` to add a 3rd titling option? We have a license.

Comment: Well, you can use renderer and set width of rendererd text by CSS. It is exported correct, as well. See this: http://jsfiddle.net/KvgV7/578/

Comment: Again, using renderer or labels requires figuring out the css positioning myself for many variants in chart title text length/contents and chart styles. Using title, subtitle, and credits would be simpler as those 3 elements are already "fitted" to the chart size. See this: http://jsfiddle.net/wergeld/X3EE5/6/ and export a JPEG. Can we mod the `credits` to use as our footer text without violating our license?